# Is there any difference between ZIP files?

Tags: c#, zip, winrar, winzip

I created a ZIP file by using Windows compress and then I created another ZIP file by using *WinRAR*. In my output I have two different set of output!

List of folders do not appear in the ZIP file generated by Windows, but I have a list of folders as well with *WinRAR* created ZIP file.

- Which one is the correct archive?
- Have you ever faced with this issue?
- How can I handle this situation?
- Is there any other model also?

**Output of Windows compressed ZIP file:**

```
DirectoryName:data FileName:data.bin
DirectoryName: FileName:manifest.txt
DirectoryName:pdfs FileName:some.pdf
```

**Output of WinRAR ZIP file:**

```
DirectoryName: FileName:manifest.txt
DirectoryName:data FileName:
DirectoryName:data FileName:data.bin
DirectoryName:pdfs FileName:
DirectoryName:pdfs FileName:some.pdf
```

I am using this code for generating above output:

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
{
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        TreeNodeDetails tnd = new TreeNodeDetails(entry.FullName, seq_folder_id++, NODETYPE.ZIPFILE, NODE_Format.DIRECTORY);
        Console.WriteLine("DirectoryName:" + tnd.directoryName + " FileName:" + tnd.fileName);
        InitiateTree(rootTreeNode, tnd);
    }
}
```

Comment: The ZIP file created with WinRAR was created implicit with `"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -ep1 -r Example.zip C:\Temp\ExampleFolder\*` which results in adding also directory entries to the ZIP archive independent on directory containing at least one file or being empty. That's like running `dir C:\Temp\ExampleFolder\* /B /S`. By using additionally the switch `-ed` to exclude empty directories *WinRAR* would create a ZIP file containing only file entries and their data like running in a command prompt window `dir C:\Temp\ExampleFolder\* /A-D /B /S`.

Comment: @Mofi: Thanks for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 2):

yes there are several compression types, most common are Zip, GZip, and Rar. which type you want depends on what you will use it for, and what program you will be compressing/decompressing with, and since you seem to be writing your own, it should work fin for you to unzip as well. not much of a size difference between the three main types, although that depends on the size of the archive being zipped. so bassically its up to you!

if your worried something went wrong, you can unzip them and compare the contents, and then you can decide based on compressed size which one to keep. zip has always been more common, but most zip programs handle rar now too.

Comment: For people on linux (but not only), adding  .tar.gz/.tgz or zlib to the list seems relevant to me ^^

Comment: yes absolutely! both his compression programs are windows based so it didnt occur to me, i suppose mac has a compression type or two as well but i do not know it

Comment: Yes, anyway, with C# the target is probably windows, but since it's not mandatory I wanted to show how wide the choice can be. I remember having a lot of issues finding which library was needed when i was wiriting a driver for camera where one of the file was compressed with zlib but nobody told me ><

Comment: @PrinceOfRavens: I am using ZipArchive, do I need to specify anything especial when I am loading my zip file?

Comment: @Mikitori:I added more part of code, can you confirm the way I am loading my zip file is file or I need to consider something else?

Comment: @PrinceOfRavens: I also didn't get you, what do u mean by "most common are Zip, GZip, and Rar. which type you want depends on what you will use it for". In my scenario I am receiving a zip file from user and I am not sure with which software it is created.

Comment: no your file seems to be zipping fine on both cases, thats why i said to extract em both and make sure they are both correct. if so you can use either one you want.

Comment: First, are you sure the provided file is correct? Have you tried with a zip file you created yourself? last time I had issues with zip was in C++, but I'm pretty sure ZipArchive class doesn't support any format. Do you have any clue on how your user created it? can you trust the file extension? A bit of context may help.

Answer (score 1):

There's no functional difference between the two examples. For example:

```
DirectoryName:data FileName:data.bin
```

If the folder `'data'` doesn't exist, it will be created, then the '`data.bin`' file will be extracted and added to that folder.

Comment: well that is depends what I wrote in InitiateTree() function ;)